# Is there a way to define local static variables for all implementors of an interface in Java?

Tags: java, inheritance, interface, static, abstract-class

I have several classes, about 40 or so, that implement a single interface. I'd like to introduce a static variable that is local to each implementing class of this interface. For example:

```java
public interface MyInterface {
  ...
}

public class MyClass1 implements MyInterface {
  public static ArrayList<String> myList;
}


public class MyClass2 implements MyInterface {
  public static ArrayList<String> myList;
}
```

I need each class to have its own version of this static variable.
Is there a way I can accomplish this from an inherited class, like the interface or an abstract class, instead of recreating the same static variable and methods across all the classes that implement the interface?

I successfully accomplished this by putting in the static variable and methods to each of the classes, but I'm curious to know if there is a way to implement this in one place and share it. This project is so nestled in the static architecture I'm afraid it would be far to difficult to try and change it now

Comment: Hi. Whats stopping you from putting myList in a parent class and making everyone inherit that? Why does it need to be interfaces?

Comment: Interfaces are meant to provide a common behavioral contract and hide implementation details such as static variables. So this requirement somewhat contradicts the purpose of using an interface. Why exactly do you need it that way?

Comment: Btw, polymorphism is generally applied to instances which static members clearly are not. So you will not be able to use inheritance to "inherit" a different "instance" of a "static" list - see how this sentence already feels like not making sense? Interfaces won't help you here nor will introducing a parent class. I'd say apart from scrapping the "static architecture" as you call it the only other solution I could think of would be some kind of generator approach that creates the classes (or stubs of them) for you.

Comment: have you consider to implements you interface with an abstract class ?

Comment: Sounds like you are living in static hell.  You think changing the project might be too difficult? You should probably be thinking of throwing it all away and rewriting it from scratch.

Comment: @UsmanMutawakil I'd like each child class to have their own static list, that way I can find each list from a static reference. I don't want them all to share a single list

Comment: @Thomas each class needs to keep track of a list of hashed strings that the class creates everytime it's method is called. That way it can make sure if it's found a piece of source data that is duplicated, it doesn't spend time recreating it in the output

Comment: I agree with Mike in that you should try to find a way out of static hell. If you can't  (at least for the moment) how about having a central "repository" that contains the data for each class. A simple repository might have a `Map<Class<?>, List<String>>` and if a class needs to get access to its list you'd just call something like `repository.getList(MyClass2.class)` etc. If you have other data as well this could be handled in a similar way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an abstract class MyAbstract and put the static variable inside the MyAbstract. Then make all the method headers from MyInterface to be abstract methods in MyAbstract.

Then let all the 40 or so classes extend the MyAbstract class instead of implementing MyInterface.

**UPDATE:**

The following is the implementation of abstract parent class that allows separate static list for each child class. In each class only need to define their unique ID number and define the abstract methods from Parent.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

abstract class Parent {

    public static final int MAX_CHILDREN = 2;
    private static Object[] shared = new Object[ MAX_CHILDREN ];

    public void setShared(int id, Object list) {
        shared[id] = list;
    }
    public Object getShared(int id) {
        return shared[id];
    }

    abstract public void setShared(ArrayList<String> list); 
    abstract public ArrayList<String> getShared();
}

class Child1 extends Parent {
    public static final int ID = 0; 
    public Child1( ) {
        setShared(new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    public void setShared(ArrayList<String> list) {
        setShared(ID, new ArrayList<String>()); 
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getShared() {
        return (ArrayList<String>) getShared(ID);
    }
}

class Child2 extends Parent {
    public static final int ID = 1; 
    public Child2( ) {
        setShared(new ArrayList<String>());
    }
    public void setShared(ArrayList<String> list) {
        setShared(ID, new ArrayList<String>()); 
    }
    public ArrayList<String> getShared() {
        return (ArrayList<String>) getShared(ID);
    }
}

public class ShareStatic {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Child1 c1 = new Child1();
        c1.getShared().add("Hello");
        System.out.println("C1 : " + c1.getShared().get(0));
        Child2 c2a = new Child2();
        Child2 c2b = new Child2();
        c2a.getShared().add("Good bye");
        c2b.getShared().add("Good day");
        System.out.println("C2a : " + c2a.getShared().get(0));
        System.out.println("C2a : " + c2a.getShared().get(1));      
        System.out.println("C2b : " + c2b.getShared().get(0));
        System.out.println("C2b : " + c2b.getShared().get(1));
        System.out.println("C1 : " + c1.getShared().get(0));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
C1 : Hello
C2a : Good bye
C2a : Good day
C2b : Good bye
C2b : Good day
C1 : Hello
```

Comment: The problem is that this approach still only has the one static variable instead of every child class having their own static variable

Comment: Now i understand what you mean. I update my answer.

Comment: Not purely by Java syntax, but just to demonstrate an approach that can achieve the same objective, i guess.